# Google actions simulator does not recognize intents

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I'm currently trying to run the test app on google actions simulator. The simulator doesn't recognize my intents. 
[Example of conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llHbo.png)

instead it just leaves the conversation. It works perfectly on dialogflow webdemo

Comment: What did you investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause of this is that, in your code, you are using `app.tell()` instead of `app.ask()`.

The `app.tell()` method indicates to send the response to the user, and then close the conversation.

While `app.ask()` sends the response to the user and then waits for the user to say something else. When they say something else, then Dialogflow will try to match them to one of your other intents.

This works with the Dialogflow webdemo because it doesn't have the concept of closing a conversation, so `app.ask()` and `app.tell()` end up behaving the same way.